# how do I set a Thunderbird signature to use a dynamic url's html?

Tags: thunderbird

I want to use a dynamic email signature in Thunderbird, that is context aware (depends on date, events in db, etc.)

If I have a PHP that can generate the signature html (i.e. http://www.site.com/email_sign.php)
how do I force Thunderbird to use it?

(the only options I see are using static html (whether inline, of from a local system file).

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Signature Switch add-on and a batch file calling wget to achieve what you want. I wrote a simple executable to replace the bat file; you can read about it (and download it if you want to) from http://www.else.co.nz/portfolio/020-code/dynamic-email-signatures

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do this simply. Thunderbird does allow scripting via the creation of plugins but I wouldn't personally know how do do it or how easy it might be.

Best answer I can think of would be to set a scheduled task / cron job to download the php to a local file then follow the instructions in the [knowledge base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Signatures), namely:

> You can use Thunderbird to create signature files, or you can use your operating system tools to create them—for example, a plain text editor.
>
> Thunderbird does not provide any
>   special place to store signature
>   files. You could create a Signatures
>   directory in your profile to store
>   them, making them easy to back up
>   along with the rest of your profile.
>   Or you could store them somewhere
>   else.
>
> To use a signature file, specify it in
>   Account Settings as the signature for
>   an identity. Check the box "Attach the
>   signature from a file instead" and
>   specify the signature file.

This will work unless Thunderbird caches the HTML internally, however I see no indication in the FAQ that this is the case.

Comment: thanks, while it might work, I still think there should be a more elegant way to accomplish that.

Comment: there is something more elegant, write a plugin or patch... of course "elegant" and "simple" aren't necessarily the same thing. you're asking for something most people never need, so bundling the option with the default software is "inelegant".

Answer (score 0):

For years I updated the signature for my email client manually – until I got fed up… That’s why I wrote a PHP script to create a randomized signature block automatically from an RSS feed! Check it out: https://github.com/birdy1976/signature :-D